# Selecting an epi-illuminated objective for optical microscopy

Tags: optics, experimental-physics, microscopy

I am currently trying to improve my silicon microphotography. To provide context: this is what I get with a 10x epi plan objective¹:

[image]

This is what I get with 40x epi plan objectve with NA=0.65:

[image]

I can get very good resolution with a 100x epi plan oil immersion objective with NA=1.25, but the magnification is too large: there's over 4 times more movements I have to perform to traverse the entire IC and the stage is not very high-quality, making that harder.

Because of the above, my understanding is that the 40x objective has an NA which is too small for my goals. I tried to find a 40x epi plan objective with NA>=0.95 (immersion or not), but it appears that there is no local supplier. After selecting for NA and magnification in range of 40x-60x, it appears that I can get:

- 60x non-epi apochromatic water immersion with NA=1.0
- 40x non-epi apochromatic with NA=0.95

Unfortunately, the supplier does not accept returns *ever*.

The question is: would a non-epi objective work with epi illumination? My understanding is that epi objectives differ in that they 1) have additional antireflection coatings 2) are not corrected for 0.17mm specimen cover glass.

More generally, how would one select an objective given the constraints that I have?

¹ I know it's overetched, alright?

Comment: Honestly, I think you are optimizing the entirely wrong end of this. If you can get good images with the 100x epi at NA=1.25, that's the way to go. The remainder is a software problem for the stitching of the images, which is essentially solved.

Comment: @CuriousOne For this chip, which is smaller than 1mm, I will have to take 14x14x3=588 pictures manually: one for every one of the three layers of it. That's a lot of work. Most of the chips I'm interested in are substantially larger, which makes it downright intractable.

With less magnification, I don't care about layers because they're all in focus enough for my purposes.

Comment: At which point I have to throw my hands up in the air and simply admit that I believe in my heart that what you have is not a physics but an economics problem... how to get better equipment that gets the job done. It seems to me that a modern confocal microscope should be more than capable of doing what you need... the only question is where you can get the $100k for a modern confocal microscope. Is that halfway correct?

Comment: What is epi-illumination? Is this Kohler illumination were the objective its self is used to flood the sample? Comment: you should think about changing supplier! I've had great experience with asking Thor Labs for technical support when selecting the correct optical components. Worth a try.

Comment: @CuriousOne Assuming unlimited funds, I could just get a SEM, which would work better for this use case. But I do not have unlimited funds :)

Comment: @boyfarrell Epi-illumination: correct (although I've never heard it described like that before). Changing supplier: I'm an amateur in what you'd call a "third-world country". My supplier here is one step above a flea market (or eBay, but eBay is an order of magnitude more expensive). Frankly I was still shocked to learn they neither accept returns nor understand what they sell, but that was not completely unexpected.

Comment: I understand your problem. A former boss of mine used to say something really smart about the topic of trying to replace money with home-spun half-solutions: "Life is too short.". Seriously, if you are not planning to be in the confocal microscope production business, buy a used instrument that gets the job done. And if you want an SEM, you can pick some up for less money than you will be spending on the long run trying to build something yourself out of optical instrument parts. OTOH, maybe there is actually a business idea in there for you. Did you think about starting a microscopy business?

Comment: @CuriousOne What?? I'm asking for objective selection criteria and you're telling me to start a microscopy business? This is either a bad joke or the worst example of scope creep I've seen in my life.

Comment: I am merely giving you a different perspective on your problem. You are trying to build something that is commercially available (and by far better) yourself. That is, in 99.9% of all cases a bad idea. The better idea is to figure out how to come up with the money to buy the commercial product. I know that this is an inconvenient truth of experimental physics, but I am not here to lie to those who are asking.

Comment: Look at it the other way: I could have given you a random recommendation for an optical component for which I have no performance and quality specs and for which there is no rational way to tell how it will perform as part of the entire system that you have. Would that truly serve your purpose? I decided to give you a few generally valid pointers about equipment purchases (and one hint at how you could use what you have, already), instead. I am sorry if that has offended you.

Comment: @whitequark oh I see. Looks like you are doing some fantastic work within very tight constraints. I'm impressed. An option http://www.edmundoptics.com/technical-resources-center/optics/understanding-ball-lenses/

Comment: from @JTS : This should be a comment but I have to insert it as an answer (not enough reputation yet). As soon as you increase the numerical aperture you will have a shorter depth of focus, irrespective of magnification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be an answer for future readers, based on my experience at ZeptoBars.

For analog chip microscopy (like you have here) NA 0.3-0.45 should be well enough to reach sharp image where all chip features are clearly visible. If you are not getting sharp image - issues could be at:

1. Too small illumination aperture (typically nearly all EPI-illuminated microscopes has adjustable apertures). You need to increase aperture as long as image is getting brighter and then a little reserve.
2. Incorrect lens type: Infinity vs 160/180 tube. No good/easy fix other than replacement.
3. Flawed lens (non-symmetrical aberrations often point to that), and unfortunately on the image I see vertical chromatic tail which hints on misalignment somewhere in the lens (if this color separation is visible only with this lens)
4. If you are using 0.5x camera adapter - it is often largest contributing factor for quality reduction. You can get passive 1x adapter to check ultimate image quality. There are good 0.5x adapters, but good way forward is camera with larger sensor (at least 1", not more than APSC) which would allow to see same magnification with 1x adapter.
5. Incorrect cover glass thickness / immersion.

General notes:

- Do not increase NA when not needed. It is exponentially harder to work with large panoramas at high NA due to tight focus requirements. >0.65 you require full automation. Often 0.25-0.3 or even 0.16 is enough.
- For non-transparent speciments epi/non-epi lens does not matter much, if other optical specs are met (tube length, cover glass, immersion). I've noticed no difference in epi-rated vs biological low-magnification lenses in as-designed conditions. There might be difference in fluorescence e.t.c, might be slightly lower contrast - but this is outside of the scope, all this would hardly affect normal bright-field image.
- You definitely do not want dark-field illumination for chips, unless you are looking for dirt and defects.

Comment: Wow, @BarsMonster himself!! I'm honored. I have since lost most of my microscopy setup in a series of cross-border moves, but I will definitely heed this advice whenever I get back into it.